# Is there a good way to ensure that the changes to Scope variables that occur by two-way binding are reflected in the corresponding service variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Consider the code:

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var _name = '';

    this.getName = function() {
        return _name;
    }

    this.setName = function(name) {
        _name = name;
    }
});
```

With the controller assigning the scope variable:

```
$scope.name = myService.getName();
```

and I have used the name for data binding.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
```

How do I ensure that any changes I have done to name from the input box are reflected in the service variable `_name`. I know `$watch` and calling `myService.setName` is an option, but I would like to avoid it because I have a lot of variables like that and I would like to retain them when I change the view.

Use case could be: A multi-view signup form, where each view contains a certain number of entries and moving to the next page would ask to enter more information. (Yes, I do not want to call `myService.setName` on clicking the next button either :)...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your string into an object:

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var person = {
      name: ''
    }

    this.getPerson = function() {
        return person;
    }
});

$scope.person = myService.getPerson();

<input type="text" ng-model="person.name" />
```